# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 108900 into shape (200,200,3)

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, fuzzy-c-means

i am new in python and I face this error can anyone help me?

```
import numpy as np

for index,rgb_img in enumerate(list_img):
    img = np.reshape(rgb_img, (200,200,3)).astype(np.uint8)
    shape = np.shape(img)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    line 135, in <module>
    img = np.reshape(rgb_img, (200,200,3)).astype(np.uint8)

   File "C:\Users\sonof\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 56, in _wrapfunc
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
```

Comment: Well as it says, your image has 108900 elements but you are trying to reshape it into a shape with 200*200*3 = 120000 elements

Comment: Maybe you want to resize the image rather than reshape the image.